# Looking for a way to lookup the column number in a VLOOKUP function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I'm building a new spreadsheet for my organization and based on our use, I'm trying to use a LOOKUP function to find a specific name in a row and return the column number (or the cell at the top of the column). So for Store 56213, I want to find Adam's name, and return that he is a VP.

Below is a small example of what two different sheets will look like. The second table is in reality several thousand entries long, so I cannot transpose or list every user in a separate searchable array. I appreciate any help!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Use and INDEX/MATCH to grab the correct row inside another to search that row for the location and return the title:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$I$2,MATCH(B3,INDEX($E$3:$I$7,MATCH(A3,$E$3:$E$7,0),0),0))
```

[image]

Or Use FILTER if you have it:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$I$2,MATCH(B3,FILTER($E$3:$I$7,A3=$E$3:$E$7),0))
```

The bottom will error if Filter returns more than one row.